# Dipole Inside Cavity of A Spherical Conductor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, classical-electrodynamics, dipole, dipole-moment

Consider the following case:

**There is a short electric dipole placed arbitrarily inside a spherical cavity inside a solid,uncharged conducting sphere**

We need to find electric field at a point outside this sphere.

I simply tried applying Gauss' law for the point since the charge enclosed is $0$.

$$\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec S=0$$This gives the value of $E$ as $0$. 
But it could also be so that the surface integral of the the field is 0, but the field at each point is non uniform and non-zero.

Is it possible to find the value of the electric field at any outside point in such case? If yes then how can we do that?
Also, can we find the potential due to the dipole at that point, considering it to be $0$ at infinity?

(Note that I am a high school student and have currently not studied higher theorems like uniqueness theorem, Poisson and Laplace etc.)

Comment: Does superposition principle help?

Comment: Not really. We can't say anything about the charge distribution on the sphere as it the dipole is arbitrarily placed.

Comment: I think superposition would help.

Comment: @my2cts can you elaborate?

Comment: A dipole field is the sum of the fields of a negative and a positive charge.

Comment: I know that. Tried that. It is not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In all points of your spherical conductor potential is the same,
   outer surface included.
2. External potential is only determined by boundary conditions: 
   $V=\rm const.$ on the outer surface, $V=0$ at infinity.
3. You can see that outside field has spherical symmetry. Then its
   flux being zero implies field is zero everywhere (outside conductor).

Comment: Does flux =0 always imply the field is zero ? I don't think so. It could be the case that field is perpendicular to the area vector.